# How to get values from referenced table Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have 3 models with the following structure:

Application and Photo belongs_to Listing. Listing has_many photos and applications.

```
    class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
      has_many :photos
      has_many :applications
    end

    class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :listing
    end

    class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
       belongs_to :listing
    end
```

I'm trying to get the photos of the listings that are associated with a users applications.

I start in the controller by passing all the applications of the current user:

```
    @apps = current_user.applications
```

In the view I want to display all the photos like this:

```
     <% @apps.each do |app| %>
        <%= image_tag app.listing.photos[0].image.url(:thumb) if app.listing.photos.length > 0 %>
     <% end %>
```

But I get this error when trying to render the view:

> undefined method `photos' for nil:NilClass

Can't I access the photo that belongs to the listing that belongs to the application with this syntax - app.listing.photos[0].image.url ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that some of your applications are not associated with any listing?  If so:

```
<% @apps.each do |app| %>
        <%= image_tag app.listing.photos[0].image.url(:thumb) if app.listing.try(:photos).present? %>
     <% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!I forgot that I had a bunch of old records in the database without the association.